# What is the time and space of complexity of this wordbreak implementation?

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

I try to estimate the time and space complexity of the below word-break problem Python implementation:

```
def _word_break(s, pos, n, dictionary, cache):
    if pos >= n:
        return True

    if pos not in cache:
        result = False
        for i in range(pos+1, n+1):
            substring = s[pos:i]
            if substring in dictionary: 
                if _word_break(s, i, n, dictionary, cache):
                    result = True
                    break
        cache[pos] = result
    return cache[pos]

def word_break(string, dictionary):
    return _word_break(string, 0, len(string), dictionary, {})
```

My understanding is that it has space complexity of O(n^2) because despite storing only n positions in the Cache it also creates n*n substrings. On the time complexity I believe it's something like O(n^3) because it is similar to other implementations but I can't figure out why.

Could you please help me estimate them?